# SwiftUI - Indexset to index in array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I am using ForEach within a NavigationView and list combined with a function called when the user deletes a row using .onDelete() as per below.

```
struct PeriodListView: View {
@ObservedObject var theperiodlist = ThePeriodList()
@EnvironmentObject var theprofile: TheProfile

@State private var showingAddPeriod = false

var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    return formatter
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(theperiodlist.periods) {period in
                PeriodRow(period: period)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: removePeriods)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Periods")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {self.showingAddPeriod = true}) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            )
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddPeriod) {
            AddPeriod(theperiodlist: self.theperiodlist).environmentObject(self.theprofile)
        }
    }
}
func removePeriods(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    AdjustProfileRemove(period: theperiodlist.periods[XXX])
    theperiodlist.periods.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}
```

I have a separate function (AdjustProfileRemove(period)) which I want to call with the removed period as the variable - e.g. I want to find XXX in AdjustProfileRemove(period: theperiodlist.periods[XXX]). Is there a simple way to do this (I am guessing from IndexSet) or am I missing something fundamental?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a little unclear to me what your'e asking.  Could you maybe outline the `AdjustProfileRemove(_ : Period)` function?

Comment: I just started out with SwiftUI and trying to build my first project.

The AdjustProfileRemove(_ : Period) function takes a Period() as input (which are the elements in the theperiodlist.periods-list) and returns a set of integers which I want to use. So I am looking for the index of the theperiodlist.periods-list obtained when the user deletes that particular Period() from the NavigationView. 

I hope this clarifies?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

.onDelete is declared as

```
@inlinable public func onDelete(perform action: ((IndexSet) -> Void)?) -> some DynamicViewContent
```

IndexSet is simply Set of all indexes of the elements in the array to remove. Let try this example

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
let idxs = IndexSet([1, 3])

idxs.forEach { (i) in
    arr.remove(at: i)
}
print(arr)
```

so the resulting arr is now

```
["A", "C", "D"]
```

The reason, why .onDelete use IndexSet is that more than one row in List could be selected for delete operation.

**BE CAREFULL!** see the resulting array! Actually removing elements one by one needs some logic ...

Let's try

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
let idxs = IndexSet([1, 3])

idxs.sorted(by: > ).forEach { (i) in
    arr.remove(at: i)
}
print(arr)
```

it works now as you expected, is it? the result now is

```
["A", "C", "E"]
```

Based on

```
theperiodlist.periods.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
```

it seems, that the `ThePeriodList` already has build-in function with required functionality.

in your case just replace

```
AdjustProfileRemove(period: theperiodlist.periods[XXX])
```

with

```
offsets.sorted(by: > ).forEach { (i) in
    AdjustProfileRemove(period: theperiodlist.periods[i])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your good input. Did not realise that IndexSet could contain several indices. I used the solution proposed by Asperi above.

Comment: @user3612450 is up to you. i see Asperi's solution overcomplicated, it could be done with two lines of code in your code base :-). Important is, that you've got the point.

Comment: @user3612450 i updated my answer how to use it in your code

Answer (score 3):

Here is possible approach (taking into account that in general `offsets` can contain many indexes)

```
func removePeriods(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    theperiodlist.periods = 
        theperiodlist.periods.enumerated().filter { (i, item) -> Bool in
            let removed = offsets.contains(i)
            if removed {
                AdjustProfileRemove(period: item)
            }
            return !removed
        }.map { $0.1 }
}
```